# How pixel value range is satisfying in CNN

Tags: cnn, optimization

gray-scale images have pixel value range [0,1]. In most imaging task such as Denoising, deblurring, and inpainting we usually calculate mean square error of observed image and denoised image. However, it is not clear for me how CNN can understand that the pixel value should be in [0,1] for output without defining additional constraints in optimization problem?
Is this because of using batch normalization and activation function (for example leaky ReLU) in each layer?

Comment: Technically pixel values have a range from 0 to 255, also gray-scale images, but these values are generally normalized before being used by the model. It depends a bit on the type of architecture used, but you can use the sigmoid activation function on the last layer to make sure the outputs of your model are in the range between 0 and 1, see for example [this image inpainting example](https://wandb.ai/site/articles/introduction-to-image-inpainting-with-deep-learning).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. However, I read some paper they just used Conv + batch normalization + leaky ReLU. At least, in their paper, they didn't mention that sigmoid is used for the last layer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know whether a CNN would accept pixel values of [0, 1] or [0, 255], you need to look at its documentation or model architecture.

E.g. It's explicitly written down that EfficientNet accepts [0-255] [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/efficientnet/EfficientNetB0). And if you look at the architecture, you will see that it comes with a normalization layer to convert [0-255] into [0-1].

Sometimes the CNN comes with some image pre-processing tools to make sure your images comply with its standard.